# Web3j listening to events with struct as parameter

Tags: solidity, etherscan, evm, web3j, java

I've tried to listen my contract event, that contains struct as parameter in my solidity contract:

```
contract ExampleNFT is ERC721URIStorage, Ownable{
   using Counters for Counters.Counter;
   Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

   constructor() ERC721("NFT", "ENFT") {}

   struct Test {
       address creator;
       uint256 id;
   }

   event Mint(address indexed recipient, uint256 tokenId, Test test);

   function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI, Test memory test)
       public onlyOwner
       returns (uint256)
   {
       _tokenIds.increment();

       uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
       _mint(recipient, newItemId);
       _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

       emit Mint(recipient, newItemId, test);

       return newItemId;
   }
}
```

But my event hash(EventDecoder.decode(MINT_EVENT)) is not equal to hash log[0]
Event from java wrapper:

```
 public static final Event MINT_EVENT = new Event("Mint", 
        Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Address>(true) {}, new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}, new TypeReference<Test>() {}));
;
```

Struct representation from java wrapper:

```
public static class Test extends StaticStruct {
    public String creator;

    public BigInteger id;

    public Test(String creator, BigInteger id) {
        super(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Address(creator),new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.generated.Uint256(id));
        this.creator = creator;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Test(Address creator, Uint256 id) {
        super(creator,id);
        this.creator = creator.getValue();
        this.id = id.getValue();
    }
}

public static class MintEventResponse extends BaseEventResponse {
    public String recipient;

    public BigInteger tokenId;

    public Test test;
}
```

If i generate java wrapper without struct in contract, it works fine

Does anyone know, why it works like this?